# Avoid server time synced by google_clock_skew_daemon

Tags: google-compute-engine

I set the server time 36 hrs faster than current time on google compute engine instance.

But it was found that the server time had been synced by google_clock_skew_daemon to current time several hours ago.

I would very appreciated if someone give advice to avoid server time being synced by this daemon.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the service of the daemon. On a Linux distribution with systemd, you can stop the service as follows:

`sudo systemctl stop google-clock-sync-manager.service
sudo systemctl disable google-clock-sync-manager.service`

You should then be able to set the system time as you wish, without any interference of Google's clock skew daemon.